# Implementing a custom event handler from interface

Tags: c#, interface, event-handling

I am in the process of creating a system that can receive messages from a variety of different sources.

Using the `interface` approach, I am adding a custom event which will pass the message back to the calling application.

I've used Vistual Studio's "scaffolding" using `Ctrl-.` to provide the implementation for the concrete class, but its added the `add` and `remove` elements but I dont really know how to wire that bit up.

**Interface class**

```
public class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Message { get; set; }
}

public interface MessageBroker
{
    void Start();

    event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> OnMessageReceived;
}
```

**Implementation class**

```
public class MessageSourceA : MessageBroker
{
    event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> MessageBroker.OnMessageReceived
    {
        add
        {
            // What goes here
        }

        remove
        {
            // What goes here
        }
    }

    void MessageBroker.Start()
    {
    }
}
```

**Main Program**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MessageBroker sourceA = new MessageSourceA ();
        sourceA.OnMessageReceived += sourceA_OnMessageReceived;
    }

    private static void sourceA_OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do stuff with message
    }
```

Thanks...

Comment: You don't usually need any of that and can just put a semicolon after "OnMessageReceived" (and remove the body) unless you're doing something special. Then you can just call it like any other method (check that it's not null first).

Comment: Does it have to be explicit implementation?

Comment: Please see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/add) for more details and example [How to: Implement Interface Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-interface-events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could normally implement from interface.

```
public class MessageSourceA : IMessageBroker
{ 
    public void Start(); 
    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> OnMessageReceived;
 }
```

I suggest you to rename MessageBroker to IMessageBroker as its a naming convention. Since "I" helps to differentiate between class and interface when looking at code.

If there is **proper** reason to implement interface explicitly you need private event handler.

```
private event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> _onMessageReceived;

event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> MessageBroker.OnMessageReceived 
{ 
    add 
    { 
        _onMessageRecieved += value;
    }
    remove 
    { 
        _onMessageRecieved -= value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the "I" is there, it got dropped when i copied over. Added the PUBLIC scoping and that has now sorted it all out